# Will salesforce continue to support bringing in third party js inside lwc or not?

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, lwc-dom

We have some lwc components in our app, that took advantage of bringing in third party code (in our case, `jQuery`, `angularJs` etc. We did that to bring in some legacy code inside lwc.

The code was written by following this documentation exactly. Everything works fine.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library

But, with the new Secure Static Resource update that is coming up in Winter'22, I have questions. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_secure_static_resources_update.htm&type=5&release=230

1. Is SF backtracking on their original approach to allow third party library inside lwc?
2. Is there any other option they recommend?

Comment: a lot of customers rely on using third-party JS libraries and SFDC probably have already thousands of LWC implementations with it, so I don't think that Salesforce completely abandons it, thought it might enforce some security staff which was not foreseen at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, that update - Enable Secure Static Resources for Lightning Components - has been postponed indefinitely, as stated in the [Summer '21 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_secure_static_resources_update.htm&type=5&release=232):

> This release update has been postponed indefinitely while we change the implementation to reduce customer impact. The release update won’t be enforced in its present form. Don’t enable it.

You should be okay right now, and I guess there's not much we can know about what these changes will ultimately mean and what the future holds for third party JavaScript until they give us more info on their new implementation.